# XDR Encode function

Tags: c, linux, sockets, xdr

I have create, with rpcgen, these two file (.h and .c) with my own two structs (the environment is Linux and the programming language is C).

The two structs are these below (this is the .h file):

```
/*
 * Please do not edit this file.
 * It was generated using rpcgen.
 */

#ifndef _XDRTYPES_H_RPCGEN
#define _XDRTYPES_H_RPCGEN

#include <rpc/rpc.h>


#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif


struct Request {
    struct {
        u_int data_len;
        float *data_val;
    } data;
    bool_t last;
};
typedef struct Request Request;

struct Response {
    bool_t error;
    float result;
};
typedef struct Response Response;

/* the xdr functions */

#if defined(__STDC__) || defined(__cplusplus)
extern  bool_t xdr_Request (XDR *, Request*);
extern  bool_t xdr_Response (XDR *, Response*);

#else /* K&R C */
extern bool_t xdr_Request ();
extern bool_t xdr_Response ();

#endif /* K&R C */

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* !_XDRTYPES_H_RPCGEN */
```

In my main I call `#include <rpc/rpc.h>` and `#include "xdrtypes.h"`.Then I want send a Request message to the server with a socket (`s` is the file descriptor `s = socket(...)`):

```
stream_socket_w = fdopen(s, "w"); 
xdrstdio_create(&xdrs_w, stream_socket_w, XDR_ENCODE);

x.data.data_len = 5;
x.last = 1;
x.data.data_val[0] = 5.3;
x.data.data_val[1] = 2.7;
x.data.data_val[2] = 8.4;
x.data.data_val[3] = 2.9;
x.data.data_val[4] = 1.7;

xdr_Request(&xdrs_w, &x);   
fflush(stream_socket_w);
```

The problem is that the execution stop at the line `xdr_Request(&xdrs_w, &x)` and I obtain "`Segmentation Fault`". Everybody Can Help me please? Thank you very much.

Comment: Compile with `gcc -Wall -g` and use the `gdb` debugger.... Test the result of `fdopen`

Comment: Done with gcc -Wall -g and no problems occurs. The problem is xdr_Request but all seems to be ok

Comment: in the .h file there is extern  bool_t xdr_Request (XDR *, Request*); in the main I have to declarate something since in the .h file there is extern?

Answer (score 2):

Are you allocating memory for data_val?
x.data.data_val = malloc(x.data.data_len * sizeof(float));
Where xdr_Request function is defined? do you have its API?